# Google is returning an 'App isn't verified' error when trying to authenticate with a Gmail account

Tags: android, google-apps-script

Google is returning an 'App isn't verified' error when trying to authenticate with a Gmail account. This is happening on both Android and iOS.

Some users are seeing an error that the 'app isn't verified' and need to click 'Advanced' to proceed and others do not see an option at all.

I've attempted the following, yet the issue persists.

1. Verified ownership of all authorized domains used
2. Provided all scopes that the project uses
3. Updated the OAuth consent screen, including all authorized domains and application scopes

Does anyone have any ideas on what else I need to do to resolve this ?

Comment: Are you using a GMail scope?  And if so, what is it?

Comment: Yup. I'm using "https://mail.google.com"

Comment: That scope is considered a "restricted scope" and is subject to a security assessment by someone outside of Google, and which could cost $15,000 to $75,000 dollars (or more)  Here is the link to Google documentation for restricted scopes: [Restricted Scopes](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/9110914#restricted-scopes)  Also see the [How will the security assessment work](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/9110914) section of the google support page.

Comment: Thank you for those links. It appears that existing apps have until Dec 31, 2019 to submit their first report. I've re-submitted the Oauth consent form for verification. So, I'm hoping thats all thats needed.